# Contact Points value are missing in connection string using Cassandra

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, cassandra

I have working with Cassandra and tried to connect a database in Cassandra but it is getting an error such as "`System.FormatException' occurred in Cassandra.dll but was not handled in user code`" and addition information as `Contact Points value are missing in the connection string`. Can you look at my connectivity code as below

HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //CqlConnection cqlConnection = new CqlConnection();
        private string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CassandraConnString"].ToString();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (CqlConnection cqlConnection = new CqlConnection(conString))
            {                
                cqlConnection.Open();
            }


            return View();
        }
    }
```

WebConfig

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CassandraConnString" connectionString="Database=StudentMaster;Port=9042;Server=127.0.0.1;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Could you please advise to solve the connectivity issue and please let me know your idea.

Comment: I have one additional question related to this. how i can retrieve the data from Cassandra ? is there any data access library for CRUD function?

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string should look similar to this:

```
Contact Points=127.0.0.1;Default Keyspace=StudentMaster
```

You can check the available connection string elements here:
https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/CassandraConnectionStringBuilder.cs

Comment: i tried similar with different approach but it's not working

Comment: What is your error message with the new connection string? Your original error message "Contact Points value are missing in the connection string" should be fixed with the suggested connection string.

Comment: I have resolved connection string issue and now it is working fine

Comment: How to retrieve data from Cassandra ?